# Can we add all the elements in the variable of a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to build a program which calculates the factorial of number `num1`. The question is: how can I multiply all the digits in `i`?

Here I have used a `for` loop for generating numbers backward from 5: `5,4,3,2,1,0`

But is there any way I can multiply all the digits of the variable `i`?

```
for i in range(0,5,-1):
    print(i)
```

The result was as follows:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Is there any way I can get the product of the numbers. I expect the output to be `120`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for-loop is wrong.

`range(start, end, step)`: to get all numbers from 5 down to 1, you need `range(5, 0, -1)`

You can accumulate the result in a variable within the loop. Start with `1` since that's the multiplicative identity.

```
retval = 1
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    retval *= i
print(retval)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can easily compute the product of items in a list using [`reduce`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#reduce):

```
>> from functools import reduce
>> numbers = list(range(5,0,-1))
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>> reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), numbers)
120
```